# AWS Glue scala job fails with "Not a data file" while using getCatalogSource(..)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I'm trying to write a simple AWS Glue scala job to read from a table and write to an s3 location. The source code is

```
import com.amazonaws.services.glue.GlueContext
import com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.GlueArgParser
import com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.Job

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat
import org.joda.time.{DateTime, DateTimeZone}
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
import org.joda.time.{DateTime, DateTimeZone}

object GlueApp {
  def main(args:Array[String]): Unit = {
      val sc: SparkContext = new SparkContext()
      val glueContext: GlueContext = new GlueContext(sc)
      val glueArgs = GlueArgParser.getResolvedOptions(args, Seq("JOB_NAME").toArray)
      Job.init(glueArgs("JOB_NAME"), glueContext, glueArgs.asJava)
      var spark: SparkSession = glueContext.getSparkSession

    var df = glueContext.getCatalogSource(database = "datastore", tableName="datastore_tbl").getDynamicFrame()
    df.printSchema()
    df.show(20)
    df.toDF().write.format("parquet").save("s3://<bucket>/path/to")
   Job.commit() 
  }
}
```

The cloudwatch logs shows the following error

```
2022-01-14 03:08:39,125 ERROR [main] glue.ProcessLauncher (Logging.scala:logError(73)): 

Exception in User Class: org.apache.spark.SparkException : Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3) (172.36.56.6 executor 1): java.io.IOException: Not a data file.
org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2465)
org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2414)
org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2413)
scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2413)
org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1124)
org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1124)
scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1124)
org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2679)
org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2621)
org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2610)
org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:914)
org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2238)
org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2333)
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$fold$1(RDD.scala:1183)
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:414)
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.fold(RDD.scala:1177)
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$treeAggregate$1(RDD.scala:1246)
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:414)
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.treeAggregate(RDD.scala:1222)
org.apache.spark.sql.glue.util.SchemaUtils$.fromRDD(SchemaUtils.scala:76)
com.amazonaws.services.glue.DynamicFrame.recomputeSchema(DynamicFrame.scala:305)
com.amazonaws.services.glue.DynamicFrame.schema(DynamicFrame.scala:281)
com.amazonaws.services.glue.DynamicFrame.printSchema(DynamicFrame.scala:319)
GlueApp$.main(glue_test_job.scala:24)
GlueApp.main(glue_test_job.scala)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
com.amazonaws.services.glue.SparkProcessLauncherPlugin.invoke(ProcessLauncher.scala:47)
com.amazonaws.services.glue.SparkProcessLauncherPlugin.invoke$(ProcessLauncher.scala:47)
com.amazonaws.services.glue.ProcessLauncher$$anon$1.invoke(ProcessLauncher.scala:77)
com.amazonaws.services.glue.ProcessLauncher.launch(ProcessLauncher.scala:133)
com.amazonaws.services.glue.ProcessLauncher$.main(ProcessLauncher.scala:29)
com.amazonaws.services.glue.ProcessLauncher.main(ProcessLauncher.scala)
2022-01-14 03:08:39,125 ERROR [main] glue.ProcessLauncher (Logging.scala:logError(73)): 

Exception in User Class: org.apache.spark.SparkException : Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3) (172.36.56.6 executor 1): java.io.IOException: Not a data file. 
org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2465) 
org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2414) 
org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2413) 
scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62) 
scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55) 
scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49) 
org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2413) 
org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1124) 
org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1124) scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407) 
org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1124) 
org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2679) 
org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2621) 
org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2610) org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49) 
org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:914) org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2238) org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2333) org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$fold$1(RDD.scala:1183) org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151) org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112) org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:414) org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.fold(RDD.scala:1177) org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$treeAggregate$1(RDD.scala:1246) org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151) org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112) org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:414) org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.treeAggregate(RDD.scala:1222) org.apache.spark.sql.glue.util.SchemaUtils$.fromRDD(SchemaUtils.scala:76) com.amazonaws.services.glue.DynamicFrame.recomputeSchema(DynamicFrame.scala:305) com.amazonaws.services.glue.DynamicFrame.schema(DynamicFrame.scala:281) com.amazonaws.services.glue.DynamicFrame.printSchema(DynamicFrame.scala:319) GlueApp$.main(glue_test_job.scala:24) 
GlueApp.main(glue_test_job.scala) 
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) 
com.amazonaws.services.glue.SparkProcessLauncherPlugin.invoke(ProcessLauncher.scala:47) 
com.amazonaws.services.glue.SparkProcessLauncherPlugin.invoke$(ProcessLauncher.scala:47) 
com.amazonaws.services.glue.ProcessLauncher$$anon$1.invoke(ProcessLauncher.scala:77) 
com.amazonaws.services.glue.ProcessLauncher.launch(ProcessLauncher.scala:133) 
com.amazonaws.services.glue.ProcessLauncher$.main(ProcessLauncher.scala:29) 
com.amazonaws.services.glue.ProcessLauncher.main(ProcessLauncher.scala)
```

*datastore_tbl* is a table created using a Tables --> Add table -> Option ("Add table using existing schema") in Glue Studio. The schema was created using avro structure.

I'm able to query this table using AWS Athena and it works.

I'm not able to understand the "Not a data file" IOException. Any idea?